# Laurent Series $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-2)}$ with conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I want to find the laurent series of the function
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-2)}$$ for the following conditions:

> - $|z|<1$
> - $2<|z|<\infty$

I have found the series for first condition, by partial fractions as

$$f(z)=\frac13(\frac{1}{z-2}-\frac{1}{z+1})=-\frac12+\frac z4-\frac{3z^8}{8}+\cdots$$

But how to find the series for the second condition $2<|z|<\infty$, as in the second condition **function is holomorphic everywhere?**

We can use also use the long general procedure using contour integration, but that I know to be used when laurent series is to be found out at a particular point $z=z_0$, but how to perform  it for intervals ?

### Another doubt

And sometimes I get confused when we can say taylor's series will be same as laurent series?

Comment: I think you should consider $f(1/z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do one part. If $|z|>2,$ then $|2/z|<1,$ so we can apply the geometric series to $$\frac{1}{z-2}=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{z}},$$ getting that $$\frac{1}{z-2}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{z^{n+1}}.$$ Can you do the other piece?

EDIT: In the comments below, I've discussed OP's confusion on the distinction between Laurent series and Taylor series. The summary is this: the Laurent series coefficients are given by integrals around a contour contained in the given annulus, and in this problem, these contours encircle a singularity at $z=2.$ Hence, we will have negatively-indexed terms. A Laurent series will be a Taylor series if there are no terms with negative indices. which is not the case here.

Comment: can u answer my doubt ? of that taylor and laurent one ... till then let me analyse why did we do this way...

Comment: The Taylor series will be equal to the Laurent series if we have no singularities. If we have a pole of order $k$, then we will have $k$ negatively-indexed terms. If we have an essential singularity, then we will have infinitely many of them.

Comment: but you apply geometric series , which is a part of taylor series i guess... and you did so because the singularities $z=-1,2$ does lie in the interval $|z|>2$ ?

Comment: I applied the geometric series because the one that I gave converges if $|2/z|<1.$ It's a pretty common trick you do for Laurent series. Also, yes, the singularities lie outside the infinite annulus here.

Comment: but what i said is right or not ???  is geometric series a taylor series ?? and we have no singularities in the interval... i mentioned... i got your trick as it converges in the range you mentioned. taht is helpful and i got the trick how to do with it.... but just having few doubt i mentioned in this comment.

Comment: I actually have to go teach, but I will answer your comment if still need me to when I get back. In the meantime, might I suggest these notes to you: http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/files/2018/04/complex.pdf (I think you might find the Laurent series portion useful).

Comment: Also, note that the series that I'm using, while convergent in the given region, does have a singularity at $z=0.$ I will get these terms if my series is centered around $z_0$ and $|z-z_0|$ is contained in my annulus, regardless of whether not $z_0$ is in the annulus itself.

Comment: Also, the geometric series that I used is not a Taylor series in this case, since it has negatively-indexed terms; this is due to the fact, again, that the coefficients will be integrals that encircle a polar at $z=2$ (and similarly for the other one). Does this make sense?

Comment: @learningstudent had a mistake in my comment, had to delete it. Here's my new response: Laurent series works for functions holomorphic in an annulus. In this case, $1/(z-2)$ is holomorphic in the annulus $2<|z|<\infty.$  It will not be a Taylor series, though, due to the construction of the Laurent series. The coefficients of the series are integrals, and in this case the negatively-indexed terms encircle singularities! So, these don't need to vanish. I've also summarized these points in my post.

Comment: Great , ! Thank you! But let me tell you my point :) I knew that Taylor series can be a Laurent series when Laurent series doesn't have negatively indexed terms. As the Taylor series contains only non-negative powers. But my question was that : When do we know we have to apply direct Taylor series formulas for functions to find Laurent series and when not to apply Taylor series formula, (that is in this case we are forced to use only coefficient integral formulas using contour Integration) ?

Comment: Ah, I see now! If we are looking for a Laurent series in an annulus, then the function needs to be holomorphic in the annulus, so we can expand as normally (that is, we can use the Taylor series expression). We'll just get negative powers, if there is an isolated singularity outside of the annulus.

Comment: yeah .. thanks a lot.. that was the only thing i wanted to confirm... thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

For $|z|<1$:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{(z+1)(z-2)}&=\frac1{2(z+1)(z/2-1)}\\
&=-\frac12\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^n x^n\right)\left(\sum_{m\ge 0}\left(\frac12\right)^m x^m\right)\\
&=-\frac12\sum_{k\ge 0}c_k x^k
\end{align}
$$
where 
$$
c_k=\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\frac1{2^{k-j}}=\frac1{2^k}\sum_{j=0}^k (-2)^j=\frac{1-(-2)^{k+1}}{2^k(1-(-2))}=\frac13\cdot(2^{-k}+(-1)^k2)
$$

For $|z|>2$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{(z+1)(z-2)}&=\frac1{z^2(1+z^{-1})(1-2z^{-1})}\\
&=z^{-2}\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^nz^{-n}\right)\left(\sum_{m\ge 0}2^m z^{-m}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}d_k z^{-k-2}
\end{align}
$$
when this time
$$
d_k=\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j 2^{k-j}=2^k\sum_{j=0}^k\left(-\frac12\right)^j
=2^k\frac{1-(-1/2)^{k+1}}{1-(-1/2)}=\frac{2^{k+1}+(-1)^k}{3}
$$